# Gnuplot 4.6.5 ylabel not visible

Tags: gnuplot

im running gnuplot 4.6.5 on top of ubuntu 12.04 and use the x11 terminal. I use the script as follows but the ylabel is not visible (xlabel is fine). What i have to do to fix it? offset?
thanks for help

```
 plot "512bytesCBR3000client4server1numofnodes.txt" using 1:2 title 'NativeOF' with     linespoints lw 2 ps 3 pt 6 lt 3
 set grid
 set ylabel "End to end delay"
 set xlabel "number of nodes"
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you have to do all the settings (`set xlabel`, `set ylabel`, `set grid`) before you call `plot` if you want them them to show up in the plot.  I am not sure why `set xlabel` is working for you unless you set it in a previous plot or while trying commands from the gnuplot command line.

Try moving the `plot` command to the end of the file.

Comment: dear @wrdieter , i had tried your suggestion but unfortunately the problem still happened. Is it something to do with other things?. Please help

Comment: I do not have your data file, but if I try `set grid`,
`set ylabel "End to end delay"`, `set xlabel "number of nodes"`, `plot sin(x)`, then the xlabel and ylabel both show up.  If you are still missing the ylabel, maybe it is something with the graph window.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, this might be related to the margins of the canvas. Therefore, might be wise to play with the margin settings, for example:

```
# other grid settings
set lmargin 10                                                               
set rmargin 10                                                               
set tmargin 5                                                            
set bmargin 5
# plot command
```